# Geofencing in background

Tags: android, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence

Question on start: how I can add/remove geofences without app opening?

When user switch off location all geofences are removed. When geofencing was introduced I was testing it and I was able to add/remove geofences in background by handling `"android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"` broadcast, still have this code on branch.

Currently since API26 this broadcast isn't firing when put in manifest, we need to register (and un-) for this action e.g. during runtime of `Activity` or `Service`. And this isn't solution for my case, I want to add geofences again when location turned on or just prevent removing already added.

I do see two solutions for this case, but both have some flaws...

1. Foreground service - sticky service which add/remove geofences when location goes on/off, `Service` can receive `PROVIDERS_CHANGED`. But I don't like sticky `Notification` present always just for this trivial purpose...
2. Job/work - checking location state and basing on result add/remove geofences, at the end re-schedule own instance for e.g. 1h, and again. Short-living services (5 sec max) don't need to have "visual representation" - `Activity` on foreground or sticky `Notification` - but few secs is sufficient for checking location state and work with geofences (just logic, so pretty fast)

I didn't tested second approach, but it seems to be a kind of workaround, very unefficient for sure. I want to be fair, I'm informing users about purpose of location "listening" in background when asking for permission (also `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` on API29). So what can I do for keeping these fences alive when app is in background/killed?

Answer (score 0):

ForegroundService is better option you have, as of today, there are many Custom ROMs which kills application which is in the background.
I have used foregroundService for the same purpose and it is working perfectly.

Comment: `ForegroundService` is in fact one and only elegant way for my purposes (?), but still I won't keep sticky notification just for this (location state changes) - it will be disturbing for users consuming precious space on screen, sooner or later most of these instances will be disabled, in my app or even on system-level. There is only few geofences and big part of users won't ever fire single one, next not-so-big part of users have location services enabled whole time, so this notification is just rubish for them...